# How to install Vala app menu?

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to compile [this](https://github.com/rilian-la-te/vala-panel-appmenu), and there are several packages that are missing.

**TL;DR:**

```
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0>=3.10'
--   
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:367 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:532 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:71 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

**EDIT:** Solved.

---

**PS:** I have succesfully build this piece of software in the past with desperate google search and randomly installing packages, but I can't remember how, so I'm documenting it now.

Previous error messages are quite helpful though some are rather cryptic and requres trial and errors.

Comment: it may be a version issue instead of a package issue

Comment: Do you have `libgtk-3.0-dev` package installed, and is it at least version 3.10?

Comment: @dobey Seems like I don't, but there is only `libgtk-3.0` and `libgtk-3.0-dbg` on repository, just tried to install them both, still not working.

Comment: EDIT: Duh the package name is libgtk-3-dev. Finally it went through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set of packages needed to satisfy cmake dependency:

`sudo apt install cmake rpm valac libwnck-3-dev libxfce4panel-2.0-dev libxfconf-0-dev libpeas-dev libgtk2.0-dev libxfce4util-dev libdbusmenu-glib-dev bamfdaemon unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module appmenu-qt`

The only packages not fulfilled are `libmatepanelapplet-4.0`, `vala-panel`, and `budgie-1.0`, since they are not required for XFCE DE.
Jayatana support also disabled since it spewed this error:

```
[  2%] Building Java objects for jayatana-java.jar
[  4%] Generating CMakeFiles/jayatana-java.dir/java_class_filelist
[  7%] Creating Java archive jayatana.jar
[  7%] Built target jayatana-java
Scanning dependencies of target java-headers
[  9%] Building C header files from classes...
[  9%] Built target java-headers
Scanning dependencies of target jayatana
[ 12%] Building C object jayatana/lib/CMakeFiles/jayatana.dir/com_jarego_jayatana_basic_GlobalMenu.c.o
In file included from /PATH/TO/FILE/vala-panel-appmenu/jayatana/lib/com_jarego_jayatana_basic_GlobalMenu.c:29:0:
/PATH/TO/FILE/vala-panel-appmenu/build/jayatana/lib/../java/com_jarego_jayatana_basic_GlobalMenu.h:2:17: fatal error: jni.h: There is no such file or directory
compilation terminated.
jayatana/lib/CMakeFiles/jayatana.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'jayatana/lib/CMakeFiles/jayatana.dir/com_jarego_jayatana_basic_GlobalMenu.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [jayatana/lib/CMakeFiles/jayatana.dir/com_jarego_jayatana_basic_GlobalMenu.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:382: recipe for target 'jayatana/lib/CMakeFiles/jayatana.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [jayatana/lib/CMakeFiles/jayatana.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Flags used are:

```
vala-panel-appmenu/build$ cmake -DENABLE_XFCE=ON -DENABLE_JAYATANA=OFF -DMAKE_BOLD_APPNAME=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
```